# How to serve Beaker Notebook from different directory

Tags: ipython, beaker-notebook

Trying to experiment with Beaker Notebooks, but I can not figure out how to launch from a specified directory. I've downloaded the .zip file (I'm on Windows 10), and can launch from that directory using the beaker.command batch file, but cannot figure out where to configure or set a separate launch directory for a specific notebook. With Jupyter notebooks, launching from the saved .ipynb file serves from that directory, but I cannot figure out how to do the same for Beaker notebooks.

Does anyone know the correct method to serve a Beaker Notebook from various parent directories?

Thanks.

Comment: cd to the directory from the command line and open the notebook?

Comment: @rawr I'm not sure if you can launch beaker notebooks directly from the saved notebook. To open a .bkr notebook, I currently run the beaker.command batch file in the install folder, which launches beaker in a browser and I then track to the specific notebook from the beaker interface. There may be another way of launching a beaker notebook that provides the functionality of serving from the notebooks root folder, but I've been unable to find if a different launch method exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to figure out how to change the serving root folder, and I'm not sure if it is currently possible with beaker. It seems to be being discussed [here](https://github.com/twosigma/beaker-notebook/issues/430). The work around is to copy the files you wish to serve into the default root folder, which is src/main/web in the beaker install folder [reference](https://github.com/twosigma/beaker-notebook/wiki/Configuration-and-Preference). Might not be ideal, but it worked for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the current working directory, I don't think that's possible.

But if you want to serve files as in make them available to the web server that creates the page, use ~/.beaker/v1/web as described in the "Generating and accessing web content" tutorial.